# How can I setup a URL that is redirecting to a custom logout page?

Tags: python, django

I am wondering how to setup a URL that is redirecting to a custom logout page. I've looked through few similar posts on here, but they are all old. Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: you can use `next_page` argument to the `logout` view

Comment: cool could you show me some examples of how to set it up?

Answer (score 1):

From the  `logout`  you can use optional arguments... one is `next_page`

```
(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',{'next_page': '/custom_page/'})
```

Answer (score 1):

or just:

```
def log_me_out(request):
   logout(request)
   return redirect('/your-redirect-url/')
```